# Unable to find custom callback validation rule (CodeIgniter 3 HMVC)

Tags: php, validation, codeigniter-3

EDIT2: Scroll down for most up-to-date information!

In CodeIgniter 3, I recently moved callback rules across all of my controllers to `application/libraries/MY_Form_validation.php` to prevent code repetition etc., and to clean up.

Right now, they don't seem to be working anymore.

MY_Form_validation.php starts like this:

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation
{
    public $CI;

    function run($module = '', $group = '')
    {
        log_message('debug',"Now running the MY_Form_validation");
        (is_object($module)) AND $this->CI = &$module;
        return parent::run($group);
    }
```

Then a whole list of callback function follows, all defined as `public function callback_name(){}`.

I also have one (in the same class) which checks if the provided user login information is correct (and thus, if the user can login etc.), but the form validation can't find the rule.

The error log looks like this:

```
INFO - 2016-06-23 13:33:18 --> Form Validation Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2016-06-23 13:33:18 --> Now running the MY_Form_validation
INFO - 2016-06-23 13:33:18 --> Language file loaded: language/english/form_validation_lang.php
DEBUG - 2016-06-23 13:33:18 --> Unable to find callback validation rule: check_database
```

The first DEBUG message indicates that `MY_Form_validation` is loaded (as its overwritten `run()` method is used, hence the debug logging), but it somehow can't find the callback functions clearly defined below.

I also included language file `application/language/english/form_validation_lang.php` with the following line:

`$lang['form_validation_check_database']    = 'The password does not match the username. Try again.';`, which it catches correctly (i.e. this message is displayed when performing the form validation), but it somehow cannot find the callback function itself.

EDIT: I checked to see if methods weren't inherited correctly:

```
    public function __construct($rules = array())
    {
    $this->CI =& get_instance();
    var_dump(get_class_methods($this));
```

The `var_dump()` does output the correct, full array of methods, both my own custom callbacks and the built-in ones.

EDIT2:
I read the `system/libraries/Form_validation.php` and investigated where the debug message occurs, which can be seen in this code sample (line 734-749) :

```
    // Call the function that corresponds to the rule
    if ($callback OR $callable !== FALSE)
    {
        if ($callback)
        {
            if ( ! method_exists($this->CI, $rule))
            {
                log_message('debug', 'Unable to find callback validation rule: '.$rule);
                $result = FALSE;
            }
            else
            {
                // Run the function and grab the result
                $result = $this->CI->$rule($postdata, $param);

            }
        }
```

It seems as though callbacks are only looked for in the main CI object, but not in the form validation library itself. I could add some hacky exceptions that would pick the library callbacks, but I doubt that that's the best thing to do and I guess I'm overlooking something simple...

If any additional info is required, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I found out...

Apparently, as soon as you move callback functions to MY_Form_validation.php, they are actually *built-in* validation rules, and no longer act as callbacks.

When setting form rules, I still had the *callback_* prefix applied, which makes the Form_validation library look for the rule in the normal `CI` object (i.e. in the controller) rather than the (MY_)Form_validation class.

The fix for me was to simply remove this prefix from the applied validation rule settings. Now it finds the 'callback' functions correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try This

```
<?php

class Form extends CI_Controller {

        public function index()
        {
                $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

                $this->load->library('form_validation');

                $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'callback_username_check');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('passconf', 'Password Confirmation', 'required');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|is_unique[users.email]');

                if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
                {
                        $this->load->view('myform');
                }
                else
                {
                        $this->load->view('formsuccess');
                }
        }

        public function username_check($str)
        {
                if ($str == 'test')
                {
                        $this->form_validation->set_message('username_check', 'The {field} field can not be the word "test"');
                        return FALSE;
                }
                else
                {
                        return TRUE;
                }
        }

}

?>
```